# Power series coeffieients

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Determine the coefficients of the power series that defines a function with the following
properties: $f''(z) = −f (z), f (0) = 1, f'(0) = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

For this, at first glance $\cos(x)$ works, and you know the power series for that.

Comment: @user63782 : are you supposed to use the "power series method"?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use power series. You can just use calculus to solve. Let $u=f(x)$ and $v=u'$. Then $u(0)=1,v(0)=0$ 
$$ u'=v, v'=-u $$
and hence you can derave $uu'+vv'=0$ or $(u^2+v^2)'=0$. Then $u^2+v^2=u^2(0)+v^2(0)=1$. So
$ u=\sqrt{1-v^2} $ since $u(0)=1>0$. Thus $v'=-\sqrt{1-v^2}$ which means $v=\cos(x+C)$. The condition $v(0)=0$ gives $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence $v=-\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2}$). So
$$ f(x)=-v'=\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos x. $$